# Total number of subspaces of $\mathbb F_2^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm interested in getting a lower bound (or an exact number) on the number of subspaces of $\mathbb F_2^n$ over $\mathbb F_2$ - I'll denote this number by $S(n)$. The number of subspaces of dimension $1\le k \le n$ is given by

$$S(n,k) := \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{2^n - 2^i}{2^k - 2^i} $$

which isn't too hard to see. So with that notation, we have
$$ S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k) $$

I'm fairly sure that $S(n) \ge 2^{n^2/4}$ (wrote a little script to calculate it), but I'm having a difficult time proving it.

One idea I tried was based on the observation that

$$ S(n+1, k) = \frac{2^{n+1} -1}{2^k -1} S(n, k-1)$$

and trying an inductive argument, but it hasn't really panned out.

Thanks!

Comment: would you get $\displaystyle S(n,k) = 2^{k(n-k)}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1-2^{i-n}}{1-2^{i-k}} \sim  \ldots$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
S(n,k) = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{2^n - 2^i}{2^k - 2^i}\ge\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{2^n}{2^k}=2^{(n-k)k}\;.
$$

So for even $n$

$$
S(n,n/2)\ge2^{n^2/4}\;,
$$

for odd $n\gt1$

$$
S(n,(n-1)/2)+S(n,(n+1)/2)\ge2\cdot2^{(n^2-1)/4}\gt2^{n^2/4}\;,
$$

and for $n=1$ the claim is false according to your expression of $S(n)$ as a sum but becomes true if you include the $0$-dimensional subspace, as $S(n)$ was meant to count all subspaces.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had a feeling I was way over complicating it!