# Number of subspaces of fixed dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673637/total-number-of-subspaces-of-mathbb-f-2n) it is claimed that the number of subspaces of $\mathbb F_2^n$ over $\mathbb F_2$ of dimension $k\in[1,n]$ is $$S(n,k) := \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{2^n - 2^i}{2^k - 2^i}. $$

Why is this?

Also, the answer to the question shows that $S(n,k)\geq 2^{(n-k)k}$. How tight is this bound? Is there a good upper bound for $S(n,k)$?

Comment: The numerator counts the number of ordered sets of $k$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{F}_2^n$. That is, all ordered bases for all $k$-dimensional subspaces. The denominator does the same for a fixed $k$-dimensional subspace (the number is the same for all such subspaces). The quotient is obviously then the number of distinct subspaces. I'm sure this has been explained somewhere on the site. Or, failing that in Wikipedia.

Comment: Specifically, look at the "q-analog" page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog